# Geometry nodes: Compare point values at specific location

Tags: geometry-nodes

i have this node setup where i want to compare a specific value for points which share the same position.
Then, i want to delete all the points except the one with the highest value.

To be specific, i have these curves generated with the shortest edge path nodes. When turning these into solid meshes, the result includes a ton of geometry that is not needed. This is especially bad when generating optimized game assets:

[image]

So my idea is, on the curves i want to compare all the points which share the same location and then i want to delete the points except the ones sitting on the curve with the longest spline length.

It is hard to describe, but with this method, i want to avoid doubled geometry created by the shortest edge nodes. Simply merging the points would result in randomly merged curves, which creates problems when trying to solidify with the curves to mesh node:

[image]

i hope that, with my idea, i can get a nicely sorted hierarchy of curves which are not overlapping.

So, is this even possible or are there any other solutions to my problem?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

screenshot of my attempt of deleting doubled geometry:
[image]

blendfile:

[image]

Comment: Could you please supplement the post with screenshots of the node tree and/or share your blend file? The way the question is currently worded, it leaves too much room for speculation and is difficult to answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I added an additional screenshot and a link to my blend-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that anybody cares, but i found a solution (sort of)!

My solution is not ideal, but it works for me. I just added more iterations of my method of transfering the captured spline length and compare it for each edge. In my case i used around 10 iterations, but it depends on how many overlapping points exist.

[image]

Now i have somewhat clean topology with no exessive geometry.

[image]